# Loader div not showing after clicking yes on confirmation box

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, rest, jquery

I have a sharepoint site in which there is a javascript confirmation alert on which, on yes click, I'm showing a div which has the loading image via jquery and hiding it when the function is completed (it is a long running script). But on clicking yes, the page gets stuck for a long time and the loader image is not shown. 
[image]
The code executes perfectly doing the job thereafter (I see stop script on IE and kill page on chrome sometimes).

The code for showing the div is:
`var newdelAAEdate = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + (-7)));
            if (confirm('Are you sure you want to create AAE Timeslots for ' + $('#ddMonth option:selected').text() + ', ' + $('#ddYear option:selected').text() + '?\n\n Note: The time slots before ' + newdelAAEdate.toDateString() + ' will also be deleted.')) 
            {
                $('#loaderDiv').show();
                $("#outputWindow").css('background-color', 'white');
                onClickAAE_Ts();
            }

            else 
            {
                // Do nothing!
            }`

I finally hide the div when the function (which has GET, POST and DELETE rest calls running synchronously) gets executed, but none of it is happening.

Note: The div shows if I debug on chrome, but somehow skips normally

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript engine (which is different in every Browser, because every vendor implements ECMAscript different) tries to optimize your code.

If your `onClickAAE_Ts( )` function is doing some serious operations the DOM might not get updated until after it has finished.

Trick to force a DOM repaint could help

```
{
  $('#loaderDiv').show();
  $("#outputWindow").css('background-color', 'white');
  window.setTimeOut( onClickAAE_Ts , 1 ); //async wait 1 millisecond
}
```

But be aware your code will continue immediatly after it **initialized** that async setTimeout function.